# use cv::inrange on CV_32FC1 mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a cv::Mat that contain CV_32FC1 values.
I used inRange function to get the position of elements that have specific values as bellow :

```
cv::inRange(map,cv::Scalar(0),cv::Scalar(0.5),mask);
```

but all elements in mask array is zero but I sure the mask must have some 255 values. what I can to resolve this problem ?

Comment: What happens if you have 0 and 1 as the lower and upper bounds? Have you used `imshow()` on `map` before passing it to make sure it looks like what you expect?

Comment: are there really any values in range 0 to 0.5? Try range -255 to +255 for example.

Comment: or try testMat = map <= 0.5 as a first check.

Comment: the max does not contain pixel values to show by imshow(), Thanks to Micka I used testMat = map <= 0.5 and get correct result. now I want to find location of nonzero elements in testMat by using findNonZero function but I get this error: error: (-215) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function findNonZero . I tried to testMat.convertTo(testMat, CV_8UC1); to convert data type to CV_8UC1 but, the error didn`t resolve :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully used inRange on a CV_32FC1 matrix.

The code: `cv::inRange(map,cv::Scalar(0),cv::Scalar(0.5),mask);` will output a CV_8UC1 matrix called `mask` of the same dimensions as `map`.

`mask` will contain a 255 in every location that map had a value between 0 and .5 (inclusive), and a 0 everywhere else.

If `mask` is entirely filled with 0s, then `map` must not have any values between 0 and .5.

Try increasing the range and see if you get non-zero values in `mask`.

---

I see from the comments that you want to find the locations of all non-zero values as a second step.

Once you have increased the range to get meaningful results from the `inRange` function, simply use `findNonZero(mask, locations);` to set the `locations` matrix's to an N by 1, type CV_32SC2, matrix of locations.